# What is the industry standard for waiting on a function call nested in another await function?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function in node.js that waits for a HTTP GET request before continuing. In the error handler for that GET request, I need to call another function, and wait for it as well.

My intuition says I should put "await" in front of the second function call. However, node.js will not allow this. As far as I understand, this is because the error handler scope is no longer marked as async. I can circumvent this, however it gets **spaghetti** very quickly.

What is the best solution?

```
var accessToken = "SAMPLE ACCESS TOKEN";

const stockDataRequest = async (symbol) =>
{
    console.log("Old access token:", accessToken);

    //Request stock data.
    await axios.get(`https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/${symbol}/quotes?authorization=${accessToken}`).then((response) =>
    {
        //unimportant
    })
    .catch((error) =>
    {
        console.log("\n----Axios Request Failed As Planned----\n");

        if(error.response.status == 401)
        {
            accessToken = auth.newAccessToken(); //**WE NEED TO WAIT ON THIS!!!!**
        }
    });

    console.log("New access token:", accessToken, "\n");
}
```

In auth:

```
var newAccessToken = () =>
{
    var dataString = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refToken + '&access_type=&code=&client_id=GASKETGV2&redirect_uri=';

    request(
    {
        url: 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString
    }, 
    (error, response, body) =>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) 
            {
                console.log("rejecting");
                reject("\n\n----New Access Token Request Rejected----\n\n", error);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Request for new access token resolved. Now returning from auth.");
                var genToken = "Bearer " + JSON.parse(body).access_token;
                resolve(genToken);
            }
        })

    });

};
```

These are the results:

```
Old access token: SAMPLE ACCESS TOKEN

----Axios Request Failed As Planned----

New access token: undefined

Request for new access token resolved. Now returning from auth.
```

The last two statements should be swapped, and the new token should be defined.

Comment: Side note: The error I receive when I slap "await" in front of the second function is: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: `newAccessToken()` needs to `return` the `request()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the point with async/await and are mixing it with Promises. 
This is how your code could look with async/await:

```
var accessToken = "SAMPLE ACCESS TOKEN";

const stockDataRequest = async (symbol) =>
{
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/${symbol}/quotes?authorization=${accessToken}`);
    // do stuff with response
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
       const newAccessToken = await auth.newAccessToken();
       // do stuff with new accesstoken
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Progress made, I completely refactored to avoid promises altogether. However, the output order hasn't changed, regardless of the await specification.

Comment: Solution found! The "return new promise" needed to include the request(), and the promise stuff in the async function needed to be removed. Many thanks, and Merry Christmas.